# Gradle doesn`t sync with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

I faced to a problem with gradle...
I`m using one signal push notification and I want to use GoogleMaps in my project< but when Gradle trying to sync this massage showed up:

```
Error:Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:11.2.+.
```

Can anyone help to find a solution?!!

**Update**
I figured out how to fix it:
I replaced this code:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
```

The problem solved but Google maps does not show :(

Comment: you don't have to put `.` after `+`

Comment: No it is the massage. there is no dot in my gradle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this. You need to have the following installed in your Android SDK manager (Under the 'Extras' folder):

```
Android Support Repository
Android Support Library
Google Play services
Google Repository
```

Comment: use to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

Comment: Thanks mate, but why google maps is not working in my app?? I did everything right but still not working...